Scrapy execute Pipelines in specific order
I have a couple of spiders that are set to be executed one after the other, like
SETTINGS = {
  ...,
  "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
    "pipelines.my_spider_pipeline.MySpiderPipeline": 1,
    "pipelines.my_images_pipeline.MyImagesPipeline": 2,
  },
}

Which doesn't seem to work as expected, and I'm not sure if it's because of the code that's in pipelines.my_spider_pipeline.MySpiderPipeline;
class MySpiderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
        return spider

The stats argument is for passing a StatsCollector class.
Now, whenever my code is executed, it goes first to from_crawler but then jumps to another function defined in MyImagesPipeline, but I need it to go to process_item in MySpiderPipeline instead, as it's there where I'm inserting data in the database, and I need the id of the database record to be available once in MyImagesPipeline.
What's to be done for that? I think this code isn't flexible at all, and any possible change would mean moving a lot of code. Open to any suggestion.
Tried not using from_crawler, but didn't change anything.

I don't think what you described makes sense. It cannot "go" from from_crawler to process_item, those are executed in very different parts of the spider life cycle. So it's not clear what is the actual problem you want help with, if there is one.

First you need to define the id to be part of your item definition. In the process_item method of the MySpiderPipeline class you need to obtain the id of the item inserted in the database and save it as part of the item attributes.
class MySpiderPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # insert item in db and get back the id inserted
        # code here

        # add the id returned to the item and return it
        item[id] = 'id'
        return item

In the process_item method of the MyImagesPipeline class you need to retrieve the value of the id that you set in the MySpiderPipeline class and use it as applicable.
class MyImagesPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # retrive the id value that is part of the item
        id = item["id"]

        # use the id value as needed
        # code here
        return item


Hey, thanks! The problem is I don't have a process_item function in MyImagesPipeline :|

In what method are you using the id from the database. Able to share the code for that method?
